# Manually create an HTTP Response object in php, send it, and capture it with Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, server-push

Is it possible to create an HTTP Response object in PHP, send it to a client, and then reading the response with Javascript?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "HTTP Response Object" ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. What are you trying to do?

Comment: What I would like to do is send data from a web server to a web browser without having the browser initially starting the connection with an HTTP Request. 

Imagine there was a data change on the webserver and I want to inform a group of clients of this change.

Hope it's clearer now what I would like to achieve :)

Answer (score 2):

No. The [HttpResponse object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.httpresponse.php) is a red herring; it is part of an extension which is not bundled with PHP, and is almost never used.

PHP scripts are typically run by a web server in the context of a HTTP request, at which point any output generated by the script is made part of the HTTP response sent back by the web server. There is no way to generate an HTTP response without a corresponding request.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but I think you're looking for Server Sent Events.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/eventsource/

Comment: Yes Server Sent Events are exactly what I need. I could use WebSockets as well (http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/) however, these API's are not widely supported yet. Furthermore they do not work on old browsers. 

How can I implement a cross browser solution which works on old browsers as well?

Comment: you can use one of polyfills for ths feature, for example https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource - simulates EventSource under IE8+